# Efficient way to perform bit permutations based on a vector of integers?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have a set of 64 bits integers, on which I need to apply a certain number of "symmetry operations". A symmetry operation is just a serie of bit permutations, stored in a vector of int as {i0,i1,i2,..}, where bit[0]->bit[i0], bit[1]->bit[i1], etc... In fact, I'm just using the N first bits, where N is determined at run time, but can in principle go up to 64.

For instance, I'm working with N=4, the input is the integer 3, or 0011, and I have 4 symmetry operations stored in a vector of vector symmetry_ops

```
symmetry_ops[0] = {0,1,2,3};
symmetry_ops[1] = {1,2,3,0};
symmetry_ops[2] = {2,3,0,1};
symmetry_ops[4] = {3,0,1,2};
```

I want a function which returns me the 4 integers obtained by applying those operations to 3, i.e. 0011, 0110, 1100 and 1001. The example is trivial, but in practice the permutations can be much more complicated than just moving to the left.

I wrote the following simple (naïve ?) code:

```
std::vector<unsigned long> apply_symmetries(const std::vector<std::vector<unsigned> > &symmetry_ops, unsigned long state)
{
   unsigned N = symmetry_ops[0].size();
   std::vector<unsigned long> s_moved(symmetry_ops.size(),0);
   for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     unsigned long s_i = (state&(1UL<<i))>>i; // extracts bit i in state
     for (unsigned op = 0; op != symmetry_ops.size(); op++)
       s_moved[op] = s_moved[op]|(s_i<<symmetry_ops[op][i]);
   }
   return s_moved;
}
```

which performs all the symmetry operations on the integer "state". I simply go one bit after the other in the loop over i, by first storing it in s_i, and then moving it around for each symmetry operations.

Right know, this is one of the most time consumming parts of my program, since typical sizes are ~100-200 symmetry operations to apply on ~10^10 integers, with N around 40. Code is correctly working, but I'm wondering if this function could be optimized ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it would help if you added comments to your code to explain what is what.  Also choose descriptive variable names, do not choose 's_i' or 's_moved' for a variable name, it makes code unreadable.  'symmetry_ops' was a good choice for a name, so was 'state', the others not so much.

Anyway, to speed up your code: if you have a symmetry op that sends bit i to bit x and the next symmetry op sends bit x to bit y, combining the two is the same as sending bit i to bit y in a single op.

So start by looping through the operations alone.

For each symmetry op, apply it to the previous one, then use that new one as the previous one through the loop.  Then you can construct just a single symmetry op for the entire thing.  I am writing pseudo-code to make this clear.

```
identity_op = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} //vector of int, maps each bit to same bit
previous_op = identity_op
for each op { //op is vector of ints, op[i] maps bit i to op[i]
    //combine op with prev_op to make a new prev_op
    for each i in op { 
        prev_op[i] = op[prev_op[i]] //bit i is mapped by prev_op and then mapped again by op, giving new value for prev_op
    }
} 
combined_op = previous_op
apply combined_op to the bits, this is only place you need to to bit shifting
```

Your C++ code looks fine, just rewrite to use this new algorithm.

Comment: I think my question was poorly presented. I edited to make it clearer, I think your proposal is not exactly what I'm looking for ?!

Comment: Well, your code has the same order complexity as my proposal, O(n) where n is the number of ops (I think O(n) is the minimum), but mine avoids doing any or'ing or bit shifting with each iteration.  Each iteration is much simpler, so it is faster.  Additionally, you go through each op N times where N is the number of bits, mine goes through each op just once.  Also faster.

Comment: Your code takes each bit and then applies each and every op to the bit.  Mine goes through each op just once to create a combined op, then applies the combined op to each bit.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's me, but I can' see how your approach will generate me the, say, Nop integers obtained by applying each symmetry_ops[] to the initial state... ?